# How to make a function find the address of the function pointer it's been called by?

Tags: c

I want to implement the `toString()` method for a pure C struct. That can, of course, be done using a function pointer, but the catch is that I don't wan't to pass the object's location to the function and I want the function to figure it out by itself based on the function pointer in said struct. So, if we have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct some
{
    int32_t a;
    const char * str;
    void* (*toString)();
}Node;
```

after instantiating it, I want its contents printed the same way you do it in Java, like this:

```
Node a;
a.toString();
```

*Except our toString() will print the stringized object itself and won't actually return a string.*

I took my time and this is what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct some
{
    int32_t a;
    const char * str;
    void* (*toString)();
}Node;


void f()
{
  Node *beginnning = __builtin_frame_address(1) - sizeof(Node);
  const char ** temp = (const char *) beginnning + 8;
  printf("{%d, %s}\n", *((int*)beginnning), *temp);
}

int main()
{
    Node a, b;
    a.a = 67, a.str = "alpine", a.toString = f;
    a.toString();
    b.a = 25, b.str = "hello world", b.toString = f;
    b.toString();
}
```

The fundamental idea is to use this `__builtin_frame_address()` function, which in my case conveniently returns the last byte of my object. After getting it, obtaining the variables is relatively straight forward using pointer arithmetic and the fact that we actually know how our variables are placed inside the struct.

The problem with this solution is that it only works with only one object. First one is being printed correctly, but for the second one, we don't get the right address. So, the expected output is:

```
{67, alpine}
{25, hello world}
```

but the real output is actually:

```
{67, alpine}
{67, alpine}
```

Is there a way to forcefully "end" the frame, or reset in some way so that a next function call returns what we need? I believe if there were a way to do that, this problem can be solved. However, I couldn't really find anything like that in `__builtin_frame_address()` documentation.

*The function I used from what I gathered is a part of the gcc compiler on linux. I wouldn't exactly look for it on Windows. Therefore, to save time, you might want to test it [here](https://repl.it/@OlegPlachkov1/DizzySeveralKeychanger).*

Comment: C is not an object language and does not pass any implicit `this` pointer. Change to C++ if you need it, or accept to pass it explicitely...

Comment: @SergeBallesta There's no `this` pointer to begin with. But from what I've been taught C is such a flexible language that virtually anything is possible in it.

Comment: Yes it is! Simply it let the programmers tell it what they want and has no syntactic sugar in that direction. It was just seen as useless, because programmers needing it would probably change to C++.

Comment: @PapaGrisha You can write any program in C. But you still have to write in the C language. You can write a program in C that simulates [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)#Examples) (a programming language), but the program you write must be C and not Lisp. The Lisp-simulating C program will look like `times(n, factorial(minus(n, 1)))` and it won't look like `(* n (factorial (- n 1)))))`. There's no way that a C compiler will ever let you write `(* n (factorial (- n 1)))))`.

Comment: And the implicit `this` pointer is the way Java and C++ implementation pass the object on which a method is called...

Comment: In any sane software shop you cannot do that more than once. After the first time they will hand you a cardboard box and tell you to pack your stuff and leave the campus.

Comment: You have to be very careful with applying the scientific method to C. If something has the result you expect, it might not be for the reason you thought. If you add `int i;` to the top of `main` you no longer have a C program, but something that might fool a C compiler into doing unspecified things.

Answer (score 3):

### You can't do this.

What you have found is a way to print the contents of the `Node` object at the top of the previous call frame. That has nothing to do with the expression `a.toString`, you could just call `f` in that place to the same effect.

> I don't wan't to pass the object's location to the function

Why not? It's what Java does (implicitly).

Comment: I don't know how exactly it's done in Java, but my guess would be that the class method upon being called can figure out from the scope of which object it has been called. Even if that's not actually the case is there really no way to do this in C? Maybe there's some kind of environmental variable that keeps track of the place where a function has been called from?

Comment: @PapaGrisha In Java, `n.toString()` actually does `n->class->toString(n)`.

Comment: @PapaGrisha Java omits the called object from the parameter list because it defines the meaning of `x.toString()` to include a reference to the object at `x` as `this` in the body of the method. C doesn't do that, nor does Python (which *does* pass the object, explicitly as the first parameter)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do that, you will have to use wrappers. In fact it is what were the first C++ compilers: simple pre-processors that (among other things) replaced constructs like `obj.method(arg, ...)` with `objclass_method(obj, arg, ...)`.

I am far from a macro specialist, but I would not be surprised if you could achieve it with a macro for trivial use cases. For more complex ones, you will have to build a true pre-processor, but the parser from Clang could be a good starting point.

That being said, I strongly advise you against that unless you have a very serious reason. Debugging will be a nightmare, because you will have to debug against the pre-processed code(*). So if you want to use C stick to C syntax and explicitely pass the object, else use an object language like C++.

---

In a previous life I used an Oracle SQL pre-compiler, and debugging programs was terrible...

Comment: What kind of macro would do the trick? I tried `#define (x).toString() f((x))`, but that apparently isn't valid.